# exibir um único valor da classe Django

Tags: python, django

Gostaria de saber como faço pra mostrar no meu template html, um único personagem de meu model "Personagem".

esse é meu models.py, inseri 10 personagens nessa classe via admin do django:

**arquivo models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Personagem(models.Model):
    Nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Idade = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Espécie = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Gênero = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Ocupação = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Descrição = models.TextField(max_length=999)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nome
```

existe um personagem que seu campo nome é "Finn", queria exibir esse valor no meu html, esse é meu template:

**arquivo char_info.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Adventure Time</title>
    {% include 'parciais/head.html' %}
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ personagens.Nome }} </h1>
    
</body>
</html>
```

queria que nesse {{ personagens.Nome }} aparecesse o nome do personagem, porém não sei como fazer, não está retornando nada desse meu código.

**minha views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Personagem


def index(request):
    personagens = Personagem.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', {
        'personagens': personagens
    })


def Finn(request):
    personagens = Personagem.objects.get(Nome=personagens.Nome)
    return render(request, 'home/char_info.html', {
        'personagens': personagens
    })
```

**arquivo urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('Finn', views.Finn, name='Finn'),
]
```

infelizmente não achei nenhum exemplo assim na net, só achei usando o loop {% for %}, e exibindo todos os valores, como faço pra pegar um único valor de um único campo da classe.?

Answer (score 1):

Nessa linha:

```
personagens = Personagem.objects.get(Nome=personagens.Nome)
```

Passe como parametro o nome do personagem dessa forma:

```
personagens = Personagem.objects.get(Nome='Finn')
```

Caso você queira que a busca do personagem seja dinâmico, você deve especificar no parâmetro na url. Na urlpatterns substitua `path('Finn')` por `path(<str:nome>)` e na sua função Finn você adiciona o nome como parâmetro.

```
def Finn(request, nome):
    personagens = Personagem.objects.get(Nome=nome)
    return render(request, 'home/char_info.html', {
        'personagens': personagens
    })
```

Comment: não funcionou, agora dá esse erro: ```Reverse for 'Finn' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<nome>[^/]+)$']```

Comment: o primeiro template é o index.html, ```{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block conteudo %}
{% load static %}

<div class="content">
    </br>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Lista de Personagens</h1>
    <ul class="chars">
        <li class="finn">
            <a href="{% url 'Finn' %}">
                <figure>
                    <img src="{% static 'finn.png' %}">
                    <figcaption></figcaption>
                </figure>
            </a>
        </li> ``` será que o problema é essa url: ```<a href="{% url 'Finn' %}">``` ?

Comment: Na verdade só a busca dinamica que não funcionou, quando eu só mudei essa linha:```personagens = Personagem.objects.get(Nome='Finn')``` buscou o nome do personagem direitinho, mas essa parte da busca dinamica só da esse "Reverse for 'Finn' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<nome>[^/]+)$']"